# Need help on wiring on these kind of outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

I live in the philippines, and i'm no electrician.

but I have some ideas about wiring.

I want to know how these 2 separate outlets should be wired correctly on one power source(only 2 wires).

They are called 2-gang universal outlet, there are 2 kinds of it that I have, as shown in the image.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The upper one, notice how one slot is slightly taller than the other.  That one is neutral.   Now depending on where you are exactly in the Philippines, sometimes there isn't a neutral wire at all, and the two legs are two hots, both 120V from ground, in which case it doesn't matter.

To connect the second socket, you go buy some 12 AWG wire and use the extra holes to jumper to the second socket.  Use white or light blue for neutral.

On the lower socket, **throw that Chinese cheapie in the trash** before it burns your house down.  It's not the Chinese that's the problem, it's

- The socket promises ground, but you cannot provide ground.  That means you can plug in devices which depend on grounding to be safe, which is not safe!
- Trying to accommodate so many types of plug, it doesn't do any of them well. You risk series arcing on any load bigger than a cell phone charger.
- if your house has neutral, Type A/B plugs expect neutral on the left, whereas Type G plugs expect neutral on the right.  This matters if the tool isn't double insulated, and lots of A/B/G devices do depend on polarization and/or grounding for safety.

Polarization is why the upper socket has a taller slot on the left.  Polarization means "this pin is near ground" which is something you cannot promise in many places in the Philippines.   This varies block by block, it depends how your block's supply transformer is jumpered.

The upper "universal" one isn't so good either.  It takes two kinds of plugs: a Europlug, which is fine, but it also takes an American style NEMA 1-15.  The latter socket also takes a NEMA 1-15. **Those are only for 100-127V power**.  It is quite the habit in the Philippines to fit NEMA 1 and 5 onto 240V appliances.  That should not be done, and yes, I know "everybody does it".  Change them to some sort of Europlug, Schuko, Russian, British or Australian plugs, or even the very similar American NEMA 2 or 6 which are actually for 240V. Anything but NEMA 1 or 5.

I know Euro style plugs are a morass of conflicting designs, but settle on one and fit those sockets and plugs.  Combo sockets are no good generally.

The Philippines have three styles of power in use:

- 220V European style power, with neutral grounded, the standard on 4-1/2 continents.
- 220V Philippines special, with ground halfway (110V) between the two wires, neither is neutral.  At some point in the future, they plan to move the ground jumper on the transformer to make it the first style.
- 110V  North American style, with neutral grounded. The latter is now outlawed because Freedom(tm). These are slowly being converted to the second style, which is easy to do.  They cannot leap from this style to #1 in one step or they'll smoke everyone's appliances.